# Multipeer connectivity advertiser not accepting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, objective-c-blocks, multipeer-connectivity

Having issues with Multipeer connectivity accepting incoming invitations from another peer. I have narrowed it down the the invitationHandler block code. The request is send from one peer to the advertiser, with the request being seen in didReceiveInvitationFromPeer: delegate method but the block for responding back to that request seems to fail regardless i.e the response is never sent and the didChangeState: delegate method times out on the peer who sent the request.

Code looks like:

**Invitation request sent from peer**

```
[[[_appDelegate mcManager]browser] invitePeer:_chosenBroadcast toSession:[[_appDelegate mcManager]session] withContext:initialData timeout:0];
```

(You can leave timeout at 0 as the default time out will be applied i.e 30 secs)

***Advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer: delegate method***

```
-(void)advertiser:(MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *)advertiser didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withContext:(NSData *)context invitationHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, MCSession *))invitationHandler{

AppDelegate *appDelegate;
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.ArrayInvitationHandler = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[invitationHandler copy]];
NSLog(@"Received Request");

NSString *contextData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[context bytes]];

if ([contextData isEqual:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"InitialRequest"]]) {
   // Additional operations 
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MCNewPeer"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:dict];
}

-(void)stateChangedWithNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

void (^invitationHandler)(BOOL, MCSession *) = [_appDelegate.ArrayInvitationHandler objectAtIndex:0];

invitationHandler(YES, _appDelegate.mcManager.session);
NSLog(@"session connected peers %lu", (unsigned long)[[[[_appDelegate mcManager]session]connectedPeers]count]);
}
```

**Delegates have been set within the class like so:**

```
-(void)setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName{
_peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayName];
_session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID];
_session.delegate = self;
}

-(void)setupMCBrowser{
_browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:_peerID serviceType:@"com-audio-send"];
_browser.delegate = self;
}
```

*(I have used the debug to check that the correct variables and identities have been passed to the various methods.)*

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tested what happens if you just accept right away instead of storing/retrieving the invitationHandler?

Comment: Hey Chris, the setup is that broadcaster and subscriber. So when subscriber finds a broadcast and the user selects the broadcast the invitation handler fires is accepted automatically.

Comment: Right but have you tried just accepting the invitation in the `didReceiveInvitationFromPeer:` method? You're adding complexity with the array/notifications so it's worth knowing if the problem lies with Multipeer Connectivity or your own code.

Comment: Yes I have. I have a feeling its either the way I have initialized the objects or its a deeper issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I did, it took a while but I cracked it. It's all to do with initialization of the session, peerID, browser / advertisers. This beat question even left the Apple engineers puzzled. Anyways have a check of this guys git repository https://github.com/koppacetic/MultipeerExample